# Add a new group of accesses in the user's access odoo 12

Tags: xml, security, odoo-12

how to Add a new access group in the user's access
as the example in the picture

[image]

I tried to add but still I find in the Application group

```
<record model="ir.module.category" id="module_security_app">
  <field name="name">Security For Department</field>
  <field name="description">User access level for School department</field>
  <field name="sequence">1</field>
</record>
<record id="group_user_app" model="res.groups">
     <field name="name">User</field>
     <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('hr.group_hr_user'))]"/>
     <field name="users" eval="[(4, ref('base.user_root'))]"/>
     <field name="category_id" ref="module_security_app"/>
    </record>
  <record id="group_manager_app" model="res.groups">
      <field name="name">Manager</field>
      <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('group_user_app'))]"/>
      <field name="category_id" ref="module_security_app"/>
    </record>
```

Comment: So here you want to add in user's access right page. but your menu is being added under 'Application' tag right ?

Comment: yes,  I want my groups in other category not in application